# Migrating my client list to Sharepoint - best practice?

Tags: groups, site

I want to import a client list into sharepoint by creating individual sites/groups for each client. We're a CPA accountancy firm and have been using MS Teams for about 2 years. We started creating an O365 Group for each client and then a new MS Team associated to that client and have chats and different channels around client work to cut down on internal email. For example, if you were a tax client called Joe Bloggs, we would create an O365 Group called BLOGGS, Joe, the create a Team associated with that Group. Within Teams we would then create different channels for the different projects e.g. Income Tax 2019, Income Tax 2020, Inheritance Tax 2020 etc.

We then have a client list in windows that sits on a shared drive with a folder for each client. So every client has a windows folder and then all client info is saved there.

What I'm trying to understand is what is the best way to migrate each client folder from Windows to Sharepoint? Do I create a new site for each client manually or can I import that client list with all the data and create the resulting Group automatically?

Also, when I log into sharepoint, and add a "new site" it appears to be creating a Group within the Team site even though it says "new site" see here https://www.screencast.com/t/AhCsWd4svD 
Even after I create the site it's tagged as a "Group" see here https://www.screencast.com/t/iy2v5WEahHy

Does anyone know if I I am creating Groups or Sites and if I am creating Groups, should I creating sites?

Comment: Thanks for that info. I followed a lot of what you’re saying but what I still don’t understand is the different types of sites in sharepoint?
How can I tell if an existing site is a hub site? Also, when I login to sharepoint I see a list of all the Groups that have been created. Are these hub sites? At the bottom of the page there is a Featured Link to the “Team Site”. What is the difference between Team site v hub site v Group? ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byUgA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, lots of things to learn from this. Let's discuss your questions one by one.

**What is the best practice to maintain the site in modern SharePoint or migration?**

- Create a different modern team sites for all your clients in
  SharePoint online.
- Create all required content types, site column, list library etc.  and attach the content to the appropriate list library.
- Customize at least one site to make a better look and feel with some modern web part configurations.
- Download that customizes site template using the PnP provisioning template. Make this template ready... apple this template to other sites, in future if needed you can make use of this PnP template for all upcoming sites to maintain the unique look and feel.
- Promote any of your existing sites as hub site or create a new site then promote its hub site - **this is very important.**
- Connect or associate all your client sites to the **hub site**.
- Configure the Megamenu in the hub site and those should be inherited in the connected client sites.
- Now, the structure is ready - using any of the migration tools like ShareGate, Metalogix, etc migrate only the content to the respective list or library or folders in SharePoint online.

**How SharePoint team site is being created automatically?**

Whether we create a team in Microsoft teams, office 365 group or planner - a corresponding team site will be created automatically behind the scene - so the core of these, still the SharePoint is used as data storage. Sometimes, people ask - is SharePoint replaced by Microsoft Teams? The answer is no.

**What is the hub site in SharePoint online?**

In simple words, we can say that the Hub Site is a collection of sites connected to a master site from where all connected sites can be navigated and managed. It has the following key attributes.

- Discover related content such as news and other site activities,
- Apply common navigation, branding and site structure across
  associated sites Aearch across all associated sites.

For more details on the hub site, refer to the below article:

[Tips to create hub site in SharePoint online – Office 365](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/hub-sites-in-sharepoint-online-modern-site/)

Comment: When you "Create a different modern team sites for all your clients in SharePoint online." Do you mean create a Group or an actual "Teams site"?

Comment: Hi - I meant to create to actual "Team Site" - regarding hub site - please refer to the below article: https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/hub-sites-in-sharepoint-online-modern-site/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the details, you can use the SharePoint team site and document library that comes with the 'New Team', which you will create for your client in Teams directly. So, 'Teams' should be your starting point. It will automatically create an Office 365 group and provision corresponding SharePoint site on the background. Please note, it is also possible to automate the 'Team' creation using [Microsoft Graph API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-concept-overview) .

[Check this following from Microsoft:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/office-365-groups#how-office-365-groups-work)

**How Office 365 Groups work**
When you create a team, on the backend, you're creating an Office 365 Group and the associated SharePoint document library and OneNote notebook, along with ties into other Office 365 cloud applications. If the person creating the team is an owner of an existing Office 365 Public or Private Group, they can add Teams functionality to the group if it has less than 5000 people and has never been added to Teams. This creates one default General channel in which chat messages, documents, OneNote, and other objects reside. Viewing the document library for the channel will reveal the General folder representing the channel in the team. More importantly, if you create your own folder structure within a document library it does not propagate to Teams as a channel; for now, it only flows from Teams into SharePoint.

**Now you just have to think about migrating your on-premises Windows document library to the concerned SharePoint document library**. If the number of documents are less, then you can think about doing it manually, or else, you can use a migration tool.

You can check [SharePoint migration tool from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/how-to-use-the-sharepoint-migration-tool) which should solve your problem, or think about paying little more extra to get a license for ['ShareGate'](https://sharegate.com/sharepoint-migration) which would give you nice GUI and tons of other features.

Let me know if you have any questions.